# puppet: force service restart after configuration file was modified

Tags: puppet, configuration-management

how can i ensure that if new version of configuration file is downloaded via puppet from master repository to one of managed servers relevant service is restarted.

typical scenario - let's say there is new munin or apache config. puppet client discovers it, overwrites local files... and... - how to make sure service is restarted / reloaded ?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

An alternative to notify is subscribe:

```
file { "/etc/sshd_config":
    source => "....",
}

service { sshd:
    ensure => running,
    subscribe => File["/etc/sshd_config"],
}
```

The difference being that the relationship is described from the other end. For example, you might make apache subscribe to /etc/apache/httpd.conf, but you'd make a vhost file notify apache, as your apache class won't know about every vhost you have.

A similar dual-ended situation applies to require and before. It's just a matter of which makes more sense in the particular situation.

As Chad mentioned, if you find puppet constantly trying to start your service, then you need to add a pattern parameter, which is a regex to apply against the list of processes. By default puppet will do a stop and start to restart a service. If you add "hasrestart => true", then it will use the command specified in the "restart" parameter to restart the service.

Comment: what if you wanted to group up the notifications? i.e. avoid a restart for each change and only restart if there haven't been changes in the last X seconds?

Answer (score 22):

it seems i've found something:

```
file { "/etc/sshd_config":
    source => "....",
    notify => Service[sshd]
}

service { sshd:
    ensure => running
}
```

we'll see how that will work. anyway your thoughts on the subject are welcome.

Comment: Yes.  You can find the details in the Puppet Type Reference under "Metaparameters" (http://reductivelabs.com/trac/puppet/wiki/TypeReference#metaparameters)

Comment: Oh, and depending on your OS, you may have to play with the hasstatus, hasrestart, and/or pattern parameters of the service type.

Answer (score 2):

(I know this is a super old question, but just thought I'd put in my two cents with an (in my opinion) much easier way to do it)

Feel free to use arrow notation as well:

```
file { "/etc/sshd_config":
  source => "....",
} ~>
service { sshd:
  ensure => running
}
```

or

```
File['/etc/sshd_config'] ~> Service['sshd']
```

Comment: in your first example you don't need notify option if you use the arrow

Comment: Oops. I just copied and forgot to take that out.

Answer (score 1):

This works for Solaris 10 :)

```
class sun_cron_root {
    file { "/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root" :
            source => "puppet:///files/cron/sun/sun_cron_root"
            }

    service {
            "cron":
            provider => "smf",
            ensure => running,
            enable => true,
            hasrestart => true,
            subscribe => File["/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root"]
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple equivalent notations:

**Notify**:

```
file { '/etc/sshd_config':
    notify => Service[sshd],
}

service { sshd:
    ensure => running
}
```

**Subscribe**:

```
file { '/etc/sshd_config':
   ...
}

service { sshd:
    ensure => running,
    subscribe => File['/etc/sshd_config'],
}
```

**Arrow notation**:

```
File['/etc/sshd_config'] ~> Service['sshd']
```

**Chaining declarations**

```
file { '/etc/sshd_config':
   ...
}
~> service { sshd:
    ensure => running,
}
```

If you want to trigger `reload` instead of `restart`, adjust service declaration:

```
service { sshd:
    ensure => running,
    restart => 'pkill -HUP sshd', # if service support such reload
}
```